# 機械学習に必要なマシンパワーについて

Tags: tensorflow

これからTensorflowの勉強を始めようと思っています。
25631個の数値(テスト用に同数の数値も用意しています)について、直前の20数値から次の数値を(できれば)90%以上の精度で予測するアルゴリズムをTensorflowで作成したいのですが、Mac book Pro 15inch(2016モデル)のCPU/GPUフルカスタムでスペックが足りるか知りたいです。日中使用するので、8時間以内に終わらないようであればVPSを契約する予定です。
スペックが足りる場合はおおよその計算時間を、足りない場合は必要スペックを教えていただけるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: アルゴリズムや入力値によって計算時間が大きく変わることは当然機械学習においても起こるので、ご指定の条件だけだと必要な資源は（ラフにさえ）分からないと思われます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu コメントありがとうございます。実際に計算してみないとなかなか分からないものなのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アルゴリズムや入力値によって計算時間が大きく変わることは当然機械学習においても起こるので、ご指定の条件だけだと必要な資源‌​は（ラフにさえ）分からないと思われます。

アルゴリズムを決め、入力値の条件を見極めた上で再質問なさることをお勧めします。